# SQL delete duplicate query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to delete duplicate (service column) but not working

```
DELETE FROM contactactionnodup
WHERE service IN (SELECT service, COUNT(*), contactid
                  FROM ContactActionNoDup 
                  GROUP BY service, contactid
                  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Need to correct this query. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep one of  the rows for each `service`/`contactid` pair, then use an updatable CTE:

```
with todelete as (
      select ca.*, row_number() over (partition by service, contactid order by service) as seqnum
      from ContactActionNoDup as ca
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: what is ca.* and I don't understand